# mixing objective-c and swift when subclassing

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I've got a subclass of UIViewController written in Swift called 'BaseViewController'. I now have an 'old' view controller called 'ViewController1' written in Objective-C that I want to inherit from 'BaseViewController'. Following other advice I have imported the 'Project-Swift.h' header file.

My problem occurs when subclassing like this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyProject-Swift.h"

@interface ViewController1 : BaseViewController
@end
```

The error is:

Cannot subclass a class with objc_subclassing-restricted attribute

and it appears on the @interface ... line.

Comment: Writing a new superclass to an existing class seems a little odd to me...

Comment: I think OP's question is just about how to have an Objective-C class extend a Swift class, which is not possible

Answer (score 90, accepted):

> [You cannot subclass a Swift class in Objective-C.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-XID_133)

Excerpt from [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-NoLink_26)

Comment: Thanks! Missed that - so no way to slowly migrate old & new projects to Swift without a complete rewrite :).

Comment: You can subclass an Objective-C class in Swift.  Start from the bottom and work your way up.

Comment: No need to rewrite it. You can use objective class in swift as it is using objective c bridging header

Comment: @peri08: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/Migration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH12-XID_67 "Because you can’t subclass Swift classes in Objective-C, it’s best to choose a class in your app that doesn’t have any subclasses."

Comment: Very disappointing ... so the only way is to rewrite my existing ObjC class in Swift ... double work ah ... I hope it will not re-occur in too many cases.

Comment: @MatejUkmar You can use your ObjectiveC class in swift.No need to rewrite it

Comment: @AnilVarghese I know I can use... but I needed to subclass an existing ObjC class... so I ended up rewriting ObjC class to Swift so I was able to subclass.

Comment: Is this still true in Swift 2.0 ?

Comment: By "Swift class", does it mean A) Any class defined in a .swift file, regardless of inheritance tree, or B) A class that does not descend from NSObject/NSProxy? (i.e., root swift class or descendant thereof)

Comment: @NicolasMiari A) Any class defined in a .swift file, regardless of inheritance tree,

Comment: @AnilVarghese Thanks; I suspected as much, but wasn't sure. I guess the trip from Objective-C to Swift and back would be quite complicated to implement, especially given that Apple wants everyone to move to Swift as soon as possible.

Comment: Is this _still_ the case, though? All the links, references and such to official Apple documentation don't seem to mention anything about that anymore, yet I find myself unable to google with success if something changed from swift 1/2 to 3/4 that changed that.

Comment: Please don't link to documentation as the sole explanation. Links break.

Answer (score 10):

You cannot subclass a Swift class in Objective-C. cf. towards the end of [this section of the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_84):

> However, note that you cannot subclass a Swift class in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

It's an compiling error, so U can not subclass a swift class in objc.

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC6Swifty14ViewController")
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@end


# if defined(__has_attribute) && __has_attribute(objc_subclassing_restricted)
#  define SWIFT_CLASS(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) __attribute__((objc_subclassing_restricted)) SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
#  define SWIFT_CLASS_NAMED(SWIFT_NAME) __attribute__((objc_subclassing_restricted)) SWIFT_COMPILE_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
# else
#  define SWIFT_CLASS(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
#  define SWIFT_CLASS_NAMED(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_COMPILE_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
# endif
#endif
```