# Calling a Swift Method from Objective C class

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, swift

I want to create an inheritance between a swift class and an objective-c class.

the swift class creates a person, the objective c class creates a student (who is also a person)

My swift person is:

```
import Foundation
class person {
var age: Int
var height: Float

init(){
    self.age = 22
    self.heigh =1.80
}

init(age:Int, height:Float){
    self.age=age
    self.height=height
}
}
```

the Objective-c student is:

student.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Praktikum2a-Swift.h"

@interface student : person

@property (nonatomic) int studentID;

-(void)setStudentID:(int)stdID;

@end
```

student.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Praktikum2a-Swift.h"
#import "student.h"

@implementation student

-(id)init{
    return [self initWithStudentID:1337];
}

-(id)initWithStudentID:(int)stdID{
    self=[super init];
    if(self){
        [self setStudentID:stdID];
    }
}

@end
```

and the main:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "student.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        student *hugo = [[student alloc] init];

        [hugo setAge: 22 setHeight: 1.80];


        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The Project and Package name is Praktikum2a

basically i can't figure out, why my student isn't a person... =/

Comment: possible duplicate of [mixing objective-c and swift when subclassing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24204211/mixing-objective-c-and-swift-when-subclassing)

Comment: On a side note, class names should always be capitalized.

Comment: so i cant subclass a swift class in objective c? =/

Answer (score 0):

It says on this page: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_77

> Note that you cannot subclass a Swift class in Objective-C